# discord.py changing bot status

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to change my bot status but i keep on getting this error.

`TypeError: Client.__init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents`

my code

```
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('bruh'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('brah')

client = discord.Client(activity=discord.Game('Beep Boop'))
```

i added the intents to my code but i am still getting the same error message. I tried to google but all the answers are from pre discord.py v2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You redefined the client in line 14 and didn't pass the intents keyword argument. And if you want to change the bot's status, just put it in the first client constructor.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents, activity=discord.Game('Beep Boop'))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('bruh'):
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('brah')

# client = discord.Client(activity=discord.Game('Beep Boop'))
```